# Accidentally ran rake db:drop is there anyway to get my data back?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Hi I accidentally ran rake db:drop on my dev environment rather than my development environment, now I've lost all my dev data, is there anyway to get it back?

Comment: is it deployed somewhere, or the data was on local machine?

Comment: A local machine

Comment: ask your colleague to give you db dump from his machine.

Comment: I have no colleagues to ask

Comment: well, sorry mate..I dnt think it can be recovered..

Answer (score 1):

This one of the reasons I think having a proper seed file is a good idea. Your dev database should be expendable, you're only using it for development and testing anyways.

I would suggest creating a seed file that will populate the database with everything you need with one command. `Faker` has a pretty fun gem, if you want a quick solution for dummy data.